# Why doesn't the twitter share button is not displayed

Tags: twitter, share

I am baffled as to why the twitter share button is not displayed.

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none" data-url="mobiles.bunkerhill.com">Tweet</a>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j3m1s1a2/) that only contains the HTML shown above.

I got the share HTML from a Fancybox example. Here is a link to their [fancybox jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G5TC3/) that does work.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue by including the reference to twitter widgets to the jsfiddle (DUH), however jQuery Mobile is likely the cause of the problem. I will work around the problem using an image rather than relying on twitter to display one.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```